# "Can't access abstract member directly." How do I overcome this aspect of inheriting an interface?

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, interface, overriding, abstract

```
class meow(): InputConnection{
     override fun getTextBeforeCursor(before:Int,after:Int):CharSequence?{
       return super.getTextBeforeCursor(before,after)
     }


}
```

but whai does inheriting an interface both require overriding, and say `cannot access this directly'?
[what the above errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb0zc.png)

This image is the errors from this.  One for there being more stuff in need of override (yes) and another how this override `can't access abstract member directly` (why?).

And not just 'why', but hao inherit an interface with this aspect correctly?

Comment: Why did you think you should call `super.getTextBeforeCursor`? What are you trying to do by calling that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call an *abstract* function because it has no definition of what to do when called.

If an interface declares a function without any default implementation, then it is *abstract*.

In this case, evidently the InputConnection class does not define a default implementation for this function. `InputConnection.getTextBeforeCursor()` is abstract, so you cannot call it using `super.getTextBeforeCursor()`.

To do this correctly, it is up to you to define the content of this function and how it will behave without any reliance on a `super` version of this function.

Comment: wow thank you i finally understand.  your answer > all other stack overflow answers on 'cant access abstract member'